# AngularJs/Javascript , Copy Object is good practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm wrote some todo list app, to understand how to be more expert.

**what i'm try to understand:**

my problem is when user click on task to edit, because it passed by reference so if user edit task, it will change directly the task object.
(i attached my code here).

my questions:

1) in my code i wrote one way to fix it, by clone object every time.
it good practice ? if no how you recommend me to fix it?

2) because i do not want my code only work, i want to be more expert.
if you think my thinking and planning of this code is bad? how you write this app? ( i talk here only about functional, add, edit, list of task)

thanks for help :)

link to plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/CA99iiydbD4TWaGtJZZf?p=preview

code:
HTML

```
<html ng-app="todos">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="main">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="task in todosBL.tasks" ng-click="editMode.edit(task)">{{ task.content}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="text" ng-model="task">
        <input type="button" value="add task" ng-click="add(task)">
        <!--//for edit-->
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="editMode.task.content">
            <input type="button" value="save task" ng-click="editMode.save(editMode.task)">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT:

```
(function() {
    var Task = (function() {
        var counter = 0;
        return function(content, isDone) {
            this.id = counter++;
            this.content = content;
            this.isDone = isDone || false;
        }
    }());
    var app = angular.module('todos',[])
    .service('todosBL', function() {
        this.tasks = [];
        this.add = function(content) {        
            this.tasks.push(new Task(content));
        }

        this.update = function(editedTask) {
            var i = this.tasks.findIndex(function(task){
                return task.id === editedTask.id
            });
            this.tasks[i] = editedTask;
        }

    })
    .controller('main', function($scope, todosBL) {
        $scope.todosBL = todosBL;
        $scope.add = function(task) {
            todosBL.add(task);
            $scope.task = null;
        }
        $scope.editMode = {
            task: {},
            edit: function(task) {
                this.task = task;
                //BECAUSE I PASS TASK BY REFERNCE WHEN USER EDIT TASK IT CHANGE TASK DIRECTLY ,
                // IF I CLONE OBJECT EVERY TIME, IT FIX BY REFERENCE PROBLEM.
                // MY QUESTION IF HAVE OTHER WAY TO SLOVE THIS. MABY OTHER WAY TO THINK ABOUT APP LIKE THIS.
                // for(key in task) {
                //     this.task[key] = task[key];
                // }
            },
            save: function(task) {
                todosBL.update(task);
                this.task = {};
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

Comment: I think this is more fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as your code works but you want opinions on it.

Comment: In my humble opinion, you have complicated your app. External functions, factories for such a simple app?

Comment: thank you for answer, but sure it complicated for this app. my question is not about this app. i ask about thinking or planning code.
i give this app for example my question.
what i'm try to understand if have more expert way to write this functioniality

Comment: I didn't look at your application for very long. But I can tell you that if you want to get better, you need to follow best practices, For one thing, you should not be referencing the $scope object in your controller. If you still want to use controllers (components are preferred), you should at least use the Controller As syntax as recommended by John Papa in this [link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your controller is over complicated. The service should implement some BL like data verification and posting it to the server and/or local storage but not searching for index, it does silly things now!

In order to satisfy all your requirements one just needs a controller:

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.tasks = [];

  $scope.add = function(content){

    $scope.tasks.push(new Task(content));
    $scope.content = null;
  }
  $scope.edit = function(task){
    $scope.currentlyEditing = task;
    $scope.editText = task.content;
  }

  $scope.save= function(){
    $scope.currentlyEditing.content = $scope.editText;
    $scope.editText = null;
    $scope.currentlyEditing = null;
    mySuperSeriousService.postToServer.then(result=> {
        alert('Success');
    })
  }
});
```

and template like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="edit(task)">{{ task.content}}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" ng-model="content">
    <button ng-click="add(content)">Add Task</button>
    <!--//for edit-->
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="editText" ng-disabled="!currentlyEditing">
        <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

So it's 2 times shorter. Here's the plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/nN8kd5ErSDsBu6Exm1YO)

Comment: thank you all!, in my code i realy dont ask about all code i worte simple example for other question. but i learn more :) so it better.
i ask about copy object is good practice ?  i try to understand if i want edit some object it ok to copy object?

Answer (score 1):

> my problem is when user click on task to edit, because it passed by reference so if user edit task, it will change directly the task object. (i attached my code here).

For solving this problem, you should make a copy of your model and change it (in edit function): `this.task = angular.copy(task);`

---

> in my code i wrote one way to fix it, by clone object every time. it good practice ? if no how you recommend me to fix it?

As I said, making copy is much more logical !

---

> because i do not want my code only work, i want to be more expert. if you think my thinking and planning of this code is bad? how you write this app? ( i talk here only about functional, add, edit, list of task)

1) I don't know why you are using an array of objects ? your tasks are just strings ! so it can be better if you use an array of strings. then you won't have the struggle with sth like `editMode.task.content`, you just use `editMode.task` !

2) Don't work with `id`s . cause when you add the 'Deleting Task' feature, you'll got problems ...

3) What does `Task()` function do ? ( In this case, you don't need sth like this)

4) ...

Comment: thank you for help!